# Append heredocument content to a file, only if this content doesn't already exist in that file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, here-document, control-flow

I have a file to which I want to append some content (including the first, second and third empty spaces visible in my code below):

```
### I am text 1

### I am text 2
```

<sub>(The actual text I append is way longer than these 5 lines).</sub>

To simply append content to a file, I do:

```
cat <<-"EOF" >> myPath/myFile
    content...
EOF
```

But how could I ensure that the heredocument would append the content only if the content doesn't already exist in a file, and that otherwise the operation would be aborterd?

If only part of the block content already exists in the file, the entire operation should also be aborted.

Comment: Similar: [How to know if a text file is a subset of another](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/114877)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the here document should only be added if none of it is present, you can use `grep`:

```
cat <<-"EOF1" > myPath/myFile.append
    content...
EOF1
if ! grep -F -q -f myPath/myFile{.append,}; then
    cat myPath/myFile.append >> myPath/myFile
fi
```

To understand this, consider the following.

- `grep -F -q -f myPath/myFile{.append,}` is expanded by the shell to `grep -F -q -f myPath/myFile.append myPath/myFile`.
- The `grep` command searches `myPath/myFile` (the file to which the text should be added if necessary) for any fixed string (`-F`) contained in `myPath/myFile.append` (the file containing the text to add), reading one pattern per line (`-f`), and indicates whether it finds any only by its [exit code](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), with no output (`-q`).
- The result is then negated `!`, so that the `if` block’s `then` part is only run if `grep` doesn’t find anything.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Please don't thumb up this answer but Stephen's one which I marked correct. This is but a variation easier for me to read.</sub>

---

If the content of the template file should only be appended to the end file if none of it is already present in the end file, you can use `grep`:

```
cat <<-"EOF1" > myPath/myTemplate
    content...
EOF1

if ! grep -F -q -f myPath/myFile myPath/myTemplate; then
    cat myPath/myTemplate >> myPath/myFile
fi
```

The `grep` command searches `myPath/endFile.sh` for any fixed string (`-F`) contained in `myPath/myTemplate`, reading one pattern per line (`-f`), and indicates whether it finds any only by its [exit code](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), with no output (`-q`).

The result is then negated `!`, so that the `then` block of the `if-then` block will only be executed if `grep` doesn’t match anything in the end file.

#### Appendix - exit codes:

When a process exits, it returns an exit code, which is a small integer. By convention, an exit code of 0 indicates success, non-zero indicates failure or an error:

- `grep` returns 0 when it finds a match, and 1 if it doesn’t.
- `if` uses its argument’s exit code to decide what to do; if 0, process the `then` block, otherwise the `else` block (if any).
- A punctuation (`!`) flips that; The `then` block only runs if grep doesn’t match anything (or encounters an error).