# A utility to append content into a file, if this content isn't already in the file (even in part)

Tags: bash, text-processing, io-redirection, here-document, template

Is there a *Nix **utility** by which I could append content to a file (say, append the content of a template file into the end of a second file), only if the content isn't already available in the second file, partially or fully?

One could use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449444/append-heredocument-content-to-a-file-only-if-this-content-doesnt-already-exis) grep solution but I find the code there a bit complicated at the moment and would prefer a dedicated utility if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'd like to append the contents of the file `template` to the file `data` only if no line from `template` already exists in `data`.

The command for testing whether a line in `template` is found in `data` is

```
grep -xF -f template data
```

(This is a reasonable thing to do only if `template` contains less than a few thousands of lines)

This uses the following options of `grep`:

- `-x`, forcing testing complete lines, from start to finish of the line. Without this, we may get false positives if a line in `template` matches a line in `data` partially (for example, the line `hello world` matches `hello world!` partially).
- `-F`, using string comparisons rather than regular expression matching. Without this option, `grep` would treat the lines in `template` as regular expressions, which may produce the wrong results if any pattern line contains characters that are special in regular expressions.
- `-f template`, this makes `grep` use each line from `template` individually as patterns to match against each line in the `data` file.

Adding the `-q` option to this (to make `grep` quiet and to let it exit as soon as a match is found) allows us to use it in a simple test:

```
if ! grep -q -xF -f template data; then
    cat template >>data
fi
```

The `if` statement body appends the `template` file to the end of the `data` file only if the `grep` command fails to find a match of any lines from `template` in `data`.