# An heredocument without a delimiter

Tags: bash, here-document

In [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449444/append-heredocument-content-to-a-file-only-if-this-content-doesnt-already-exis), Stephen's answer displays this code:

```
cat <<-"EOF1" >> myPath/myFile.append
if ! grep -F -q -f myPath/myFile{.append,}; then
    cat myPath/myFile.append >> myPath/myFile
fi
```

How come there is no delimiter to the heredocument?

Comment: seeing that it was an answer to a question of yours, I think you could have just asked this from him directly, with a comment on the answer

Comment: There should be closing `EOF1` somewhere, probably just after "content" is stored inside `myFile.append`.

Comment: @ilkkachu I asked him but he didn't answer...

Comment: @jimmij but then the content behaves like a string, there's no if-then behavior, no?

Comment: @user9303970, hm, I didn't see that comment. Anyway, I edited said answer to add the parts that seemed to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All shells I tested read a here-document just fine even without the terminator, the here-doc will just end at end-of-file then. Bash gives a warning about this, but busybox/dash/ksh and zsh just handle it silently.

E.g.

```
$ cat heredoctest.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat -n <<EOF
foo
bar
$ bash heredoctest.sh
heredoctest.sh: line 4: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
     1  foo
     2  bar
```

But the particular sample of code you present seems like an error. As it's written, it would just append the if-statement to `myPath/myFile.append`, which doesn't seem too useful. It looks like the here-doc contents and the terminator are just missing from between the `cat` and the `if`.

Comment: I saw Stephen's answer and I assumed it was an omission of the actual here-document (and end marker). I did not comment on it though.

Comment: @Kusalananda indeed, I took a bit of a shortcut there.